# GWT java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/util/tools/Utility

Tags: java, gwt, tomcat

When I deploy my system to Tomcat, it shows the error information below:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.XsrfToken com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.XsrfTokenService.getNewXsrfToken()' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/util/tools/Utility
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:385)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:588)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:306)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:541)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:383)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:284)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:322)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketWithOptionsProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1648)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/util/tools/Utility
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.XsrfTokenServiceServlet.generateTokenValue(XsrfTokenServiceServlet.java:198)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.XsrfTokenServiceServlet.getNewXsrfToken(XsrfTokenServiceServlet.java:163)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:569)
        ... 20 more
```

What is this problem? This application runs well in eclipse.
My google SDK version is 2.5.

Answer (score 2):

This class (`Utility`) is not used in `XsrfTokenServiceServlet` in either GWT [2.4.0](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/tags/2.4.0/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/server/rpc/XsrfTokenServiceServlet.java) or [2.5.0](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/tags/2.5.0/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/server/rpc/XsrfTokenServiceServlet.java), it was only on [2.3.0](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/tags/2.3.0/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/server/rpc/XsrfTokenServiceServlet.java) and was indeed a bug.

You say you're using GWT 2.5.0 so it must be that the `gwt-servlet.jar` in your `WEB-INF/lib` is the outdated version from GWT 2.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the jar that contains the com.google.gwt.util.tools.Utility is either on WEB-INF/lib of your project or on the tomcat/lib folder? It looks like tomcat is unable to find the jar that contains the class.

Comment: Which Jar lib should I include?

Answer (score 0):

com/google/gwt/util/tools/Utility class is in gwt-dev.jar.
But you don't need to add gwt-dev.jar to WEB-INF/lib because GWT-DEV.jar is only for development mode. You must not use this class or dependent class on server side codes.